# How to custom order levels of a factor variable by 2+ conditions?

Tags: r, forcats

```
   STP_name                                                           PCT
   <fct>                                                            <dbl>
 1 ENGLAND                                                           2.58
 2 MIDLANDS AND EAST OF ENGLAND                                      2.64
 3 LEICESTER, LEICESTERSHIRE AND RUTLAND STP                         2.31
 4 BATH, SWINDON AND WILTSHIRE STP                                   2.94
 5 KENT AND MEDWAY STP                                               2.8 
 6 BUCKINGHAMSHIRE, OXFORDSHIRE AND BERKSHIRE WEST STP               2.73
 7 NORTH CENTRAL LONDON STP                                          1.93
 8 NORTHAMPTONSHIRE STP                                              2.63
 9 SOMERSET STP                                                      3.41
10 SURREY HEARTLANDS STP                                             2.87
```

I would like to order the `STP_name` factor variable by their descending values in `PCT`, however I want the row for `ENGLAND` and `MIDLANDS AND EAST OF ENGLAND` to appear at the start of the factor levels regardless of their `PCT` value.

Ideally looking for a forcats solution but base is fine.

Comment: Do you want which kind of sorting based on `PCT` values? It is ascending or descending?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan descending

Comment: Could you clarify: Do you want to order the levels of the factor or the presented table (without changing factor levels)

Comment: @AEF order the levels of the factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dataset have all `unique` 'STP_name', change it to `factor` with `levels` specified based on the `order` of 'PCT' and then add the two levels ("ENGLAND", ""MIDLANDS AND EAST OF ENGLAND") at the beginning with `relevel` or `fct_relevel` (from `forcats`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
df1 %>%
    mutate(STP_name = fct_relevel(factor(STP_name, levels = STP_name[order(-PCT)]), 
              c("ENGLAND",  "MIDLANDS AND EAST OF ENGLAND")))
```